# How can I install qtstalker?

Tags: package-management, software-sources

I Wanted to install qtstalker, a stock market app on my Ubuntu 13.04.

`qtsalker` is not available in the Ubuntu software center and `sudo-apt-get install qtsalker` gives the error: ***Unable to locate package qtsalker.***

How can I install qtstalker in Ubuntu?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002250/how-do-i-install-qtstalker-on-ubuntu-17-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The name is qtstalker So why do you use qtsalker? But is will not work with the correct name since it does not exist in Ubuntu.
- The newest PPA I can find mentions Lucid (says enough does it not?)
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtstalker/files/qtstalker/qtstalker-0.36/ shows a `.tar.gz` and not a `.deb` So if you want to install it from source read the readme and the installation method in the tar file and use this as a reference: [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

---

- qtstalker is available from '[precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/qtstalker)'.
- I found a .DEB here: http://mirrors.ccs.neu.edu/ubuntu//pool/universe/q/qtstalker/qtstalker_0.32-3.3ubuntu1_i386.deb so might be worth a shot to try and install it in 13.04 (download it and double click the download and USC will take over).

Comment: Thanks for your time. I downloaded .tar.gz. file. I ran command ./configure in extracted directory. I got error":make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop." while running make && make install command @Rinzwind

Comment: I tried to install .DEB which is available for 'precise'. I'm getting "Dependency is not satisfiable:libqt3-mt(>=3:.3.8-b)". If qtstalker not available for 'raring', any other free equivalents available? @Rinzwind

Comment: There's some very, very specific instructions for installing qtstalker at http://qtstalker.sourceforge.net/install.html