# error while loading shared libraries: libqt-mt.so.3:

Tags: apt, compiling, finance, qt3

I'm trying to run an Qtstalker installed on schroot. Steps described here: [How do I install Qtstalker on Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002250/how-do-i-install-qtstalker-on-ubuntu-17-10/1140972#1140972)

When I come to the last step `schroot -c precise env DISPLAY=:0.0 qtstalker` I get the error:

> qtstalker: error while loading shared libraries: libqt-mt.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried going to root `schroot -c precise -u root`, then tried `sudo apt-get install qt3` as well as `sudo apt-get install libqt-mt`

Gettin the error

> Unable to locate package libqt-mt

I had already added lists to sources.list in chroot as outlined in that solution.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

@N0rbert

UPDATE. Downloaded https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/libqt3-mt/3:3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3 and started installing on schroot with dependency and as well as debconf errors.. It even tries to remove libqt3-mt (see Bold markups please)

Any thoughts? Thanks very much again.

```
dpkg -i --force-all libqt3*.deb
```

> dpkg: libqt3-mt: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
>    **libqt3-mt depends on libaudio2; however:
>     Package libaudio2 is not installed**.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0); however:
>     Package libfontconfig1 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
>     Package libfreetype6 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0); however:
>     Package libice6 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libjpeg8 (>= 8c); however:
>     Package libjpeg8 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libmng1 (>= 1.0.10); however:
>     Package libmng1 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4); however:
>     Package libpng12-0 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libsm6; however:
>     Package libsm6 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1); however:
>     Package libstdc++6 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libx11-6; however:
>     Package libx11-6 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libxcursor1 (>> 1.1.2); however:
>     Package libxcursor1 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libxext6; however:
>     Package libxext6 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libxft2 (>> 2.1.1); however:
>     Package libxft2 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libxi6; however:
>     Package libxi6 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libxinerama1; however:
>     Package libxinerama1 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libxrandr2; however:
>     Package libxrandr2 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on libxrender1; however:
>     Package libxrender1 is not installed.
>    libqt3-mt depends on fontconfig; however:
>     Package fontconfig is not installed.
>   Setting up libqt3-mt (3:3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3) ...
>   Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
>   ldconfig deferred processing now taking place

```
apt-get install -f
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Correcting dependencies... Done
>   **The following extra packages will be installed:**
>     apt-utils binutils:i386 cpp:i386 cpp-4.6:i386 debconf debconf-i18n debianutils dpkg
>     fontconfig fontconfig-config gcc:i386 gcc-4.6:i386 libapt-inst1.4 libapt-pkg4.12
>     libaudio2:i386 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev:i386 libdb5.1 libdrm-intel1:i386
>     libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libexpat1 libexpat1:i386
>     libffi6:i386 libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6 libfreetype6:i386 libgcc1
>     libgcc1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386
>     libgmp10:i386 libgomp1:i386 libice6:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 liblcms1:i386
>     libllvm3.0:i386 liblocale-gettext-perl libmng1:i386 libmpc2:i386 libmpfr4:i386
>     libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam0g libpciaccess0:i386 libpng12-0:i386
>     libqt3-mt:i386 libquadmath0:i386 libsm6:i386 libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386
>     libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl libtinfo5 libuuid1
>     libuuid1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-data libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386
>     libxcb1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386
>     libxft2:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxmu6:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386
>     libxt6:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 linux-libc-dev:i386 lsb-base manpages manpages-dev ncurses-bin
>     passwd perl-base sed sensible-utils ttf-dejavu-core tzdata ucf uuid-runtime x11-common
>   **Suggested packages:**
>     binutils-doc:i386 cpp-doc:i386 gcc-4.6-locales:i386 debconf-doc debconf-utils whiptail
>     dialog gnome-utils libterm-readline-gnu-perl libgtk2-perl libnet-ldap-perl libqtgui4-perl
>     libqtcore4-perl apt gcc-multilib:i386 make:i386 manpages-dev:i386 autoconf:i386
>     automake1.9:i386 libtool:i386 flex:i386 bison:i386 gdb:i386 gcc-doc:i386
>     gcc-4.6-multilib:i386 libmudflap0-4.6-dev:i386 gcc-4.6-doc:i386 libgcc1-dbg:i386
>     libgomp1-dbg:i386 libquadmath0-dbg:i386 libmudflap0-dbg:i386 binutils-gold:i386 nas:i386
>     glibc-doc:i386 libglide3:i386 liblcms-utils:i386 libpam-doc pciutils:i386
>     libqt3-mt-psql:i386 libqt3-mt-mysql:i386 libqt3-mt-odbc:i386 man-browser
>   Recommended packages:
>     uuid-runtime:i386
>   **The following packages will be REMOVED:**
>     **libqt3-mt**
>   **The following NEW packages will be installed:**
>     apt-utils binutils:i386 cpp:i386 cpp-4.6:i386 debconf debconf-i18n debianutils dpkg
>     fontconfig fontconfig-config gcc:i386 gcc-4.6:i386 libapt-inst1.4 libapt-pkg4.12
>     libaudio2:i386 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev:i386 libdb5.1 libdrm-intel1:i386
>     libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libexpat1 libexpat1:i386
>     libffi6:i386 libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6 libfreetype6:i386 libgcc1
>     libgcc1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386
>     libgmp10:i386 libgomp1:i386 libice6:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 liblcms1:i386
>     libllvm3.0:i386 liblocale-gettext-perl libmng1:i386 libmpc2:i386 libmpfr4:i386
>     libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam0g libpciaccess0:i386 libpng12-0:i386
>     libqt3-mt:i386 libquadmath0:i386 libsm6:i386 libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386
>     libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl libtinfo5 libuuid1
>     libuuid1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-data libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386
>     libxcb1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386
>     libxft2:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxmu6:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386
>     libxt6:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 linux-libc-dev:i386 lsb-base manpages manpages-dev ncurses-bin
>     passwd perl-base sed sensible-utils ttf-dejavu-core tzdata ucf uuid-runtime x11-common
>   0 upgraded, 95 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
>   1 not fully installed or removed.
>   Need to get 0 B/52.0 MB of archives.
>   After this operation, 144 MB of additional disk space will be used.
>   Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
>   E: Cannot get debconf version. **Is debconf installed?**
>   debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
>   Extracting templates from packages: 31%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
>   debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
>   Extracting templates from packages: 63%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
>   debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
>   Extracting templates from packages: 94%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
>   debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
>   Extracting templates from packages: 100%
>   dpkg: regarding .../dpkg_1.16.1.2ubuntu7.7_amd64.deb containing dpkg, **pre-dependency problem:**
>    dpkg pre-depends on coreutils (>= 5.93-1)
>     **coreutils is unpacked, but has never been configured.**
>   dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg_1.16.1.2ubuntu7.7_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>    **pre-dependency problem - not installing dpkg**
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg_1.16.1.2ubuntu7.7_amd64.deb
>   E: Sub-process **/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**

Tried the next in schroot:`apt-get install libqt3-mt` and got the below error again with dependencies.. Ubuntu suggested `apt-get -f install` did that and re-tried to install libqt3-mt; again the same error.

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   libqt3-mt is already the newest version.
>   You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    coreutils : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4) or
>                         install-info
>    libc6 : Depends: libgcc1 but it is not going to be installed
>            Depends: tzdata but it is not going to be installed
>    libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                 Depends: tzdata:i386
>    libqt3-mt : Depends: libaudio2 but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libmng1 (>= 1.0.10) but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libsm6 but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libx11-6 but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libxcursor1 (> 1.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libxext6 but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libxft2 (> 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libxi6 but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libxinerama1 but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libxrandr2 but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libxrender1 but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: fontconfig
>                Recommends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
>                            libgl1
>                Recommends: libglu1-mesa but it is not going to be installed or
>                            libglu1
>                Recommends: libxmu6 (>= 4.3.0.dfsg.1-4) but it is not going to be installed
>    libqtstalker0:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>                         Depends: libqt3-mt:i386 (>= 3:3.3.8b) but it is not going to be installed
>                         Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>    qtstalker:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>                     Depends: libqt3-mt:i386 (>= 3:3.3.8b) but it is not going to be installed
>                     Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>                     Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                     Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                     Recommends: qtstalker-doc:i386 (= 0.36-2) but it is not installable
>    qtstalker-plugin-mysql:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>                                  Depends: libqt3-mt:i386 (>= 3:3.3.8b) but it is not going to be installed
>                                  Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>    qtstalker-quote-plugins:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>                                   Depends: libqt3-mt:i386 (>= 3:3.3.8b) but it is not going to be installed
>                                   Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>    ta-lib0-dev:i386 : Depends: libc6-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
>                                libc-dev:i386
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Thanks again.

****Per @N0rbert's advice I reinstalled. Qtstalker launced, but crashed **** with an error in the comments at first try of data retrieval.

During the re-installation, at the last command `dpkg -i --force-all *.deb` to install packages. I get the following errors. Not sure what's going on, **it encountered errors libqt3-mt** Perhaps that's the reason...

> Preparing to replace libdb4.6:i386 4.6.21-16 (using
>   libdb4.6_4.6.21-16_i386.deb) ... Unpacking replacement libdb4.6:i386
>   ... Preparing to replace libmysqlclient15off:i386 5.0.92-b23.87.lenny
>   (using libmysqlclient15off_5.0.92-b23.87.lenny_i386.deb) ... Unpacking
>   replacement libmysqlclient15off:i386 ... Selecting previously
>   unselected package libqt3-mt. dpkg: error processing
>   libqt3-mt_3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--install):  libqt3-mt:
>   3:3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with
>   libqt3-mt:i386 3:3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3 (Multi-Arch: no) which is currently
>   installed Preparing to replace libqtstalker0-dev:i386 0.36-2 (using
>   libqtstalker0-dev_0.36-2_i386.deb) ... Unpacking replacement
>   libqtstalker0-dev:i386 ... Preparing to replace libqtstalker0:i386
>   0.36-2 (using libqtstalker0_0.36-2_i386.deb) ... Unpacking replacement libqtstalker0:i386 ... Preparing to replace libta-lib0:i386 0.4.0-2
>   (using libta-lib0_0.4.0-2_i386.deb) ... Unpacking replacement
>   libta-lib0:i386 ... Preparing to replace qtstalker-doc 0.36-2 (using
>   qtstalker-doc_0.36-2_all.deb) ... Unpacking replacement qtstalker-doc
>   ... Preparing to replace qtstalker-plugin-mysql:i386 0.36.0-1 (using
>   qtstalker-plugin-mysql_0.36.0-1_i386.deb) ... Unpacking replacement
>   qtstalker-plugin-mysql:i386 ... Preparing to replace
>   qtstalker-quote-plugins:i386 0.36-2 (using
>   qtstalker-quote-plugins_0.36-2_i386.deb) ... Unpacking replacement
>   qtstalker-quote-plugins:i386 ... Preparing to replace qtstalker:i386
>   0.36-2 (using qtstalker_0.36-2_i386.deb) ... Unpacking replacement qtstalker:i386 ... Preparing to replace ta-lib0-dev:i386 0.4.0-2
>   (using ta-lib0-dev_0.4.0-2_i386.deb) ... Unpacking replacement
>   ta-lib0-dev:i386 ... Setting up libdb4.6:i386 (4.6.21-16) ... Setting
>   up libmysqlclient15off:i386 (5.0.92-b23.87.lenny) ... dpkg: also
>   configuring `libqt3-mt:i386' (required by`libqtstalker0:i386')
>   Setting up libta-lib0:i386 (0.4.0-2) ... Setting up qtstalker-doc
>   (0.36-2) ... dpkg: also configuring `libqt3-mt:i386' (required by`
>   qtstalker-plugin-mysql:i386') dpkg: also configuring `libqt3-mt:i386'
>   (required by`qtstalker-quote-plugins:i386') dpkg: also configuring
>   `libqt3-mt:i386' (required by`qtstalker:i386') Setting up
>   ta-lib0-dev:i386 (0.4.0-2) ... Setting up libqt3-mt:i386
>   (3:3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3) ... Setting up libqtstalker0:i386 (0.36-2) ...
>   dpkg: error processing libqt3-mt:i386 (--install):  package
>   libqt3-mt:i386 is already installed and configured Setting up
>   qtstalker-plugin-mysql:i386 (0.36.0-1) ... dpkg: error processing
>   libqt3-mt:i386 (--install):  package libqt3-mt:i386 is already
>   installed and configured Setting up qtstalker-quote-plugins:i386
>   (0.36-2) ... dpkg: error processing libqt3-mt:i386 (--install): 
>   package libqt3-mt:i386 is already installed and configured Setting up
>   qtstalker:i386 (0.36-2) ... Setting up libqtstalker0-dev:i386 (0.36-2)
>   ... Processing triggers for libc-bin ... ldconfig deferred processing
>   now taking place
>   **Errors were encountered while processing:  libqt3-mt_3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb  libqt3-mt:i386  libqt3-mt:i386 
>   libqt3-mt:i386**

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see:

> ````
> $ apt-cache policy libqt3-mt
> libqt3-mt:
>   Installed: (none)   
>   Candidate: 3:3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3  
>   Version table:
>      3:3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3 0
>         990 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
>      3:3.3.8-b-6ubuntu2 0
>         500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main amd64 Packages
>      3:3.3.8-b-0ubuntu3 0
>         500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy/main amd64 Packages
>      3:3.3.6-1ubuntu3 0
>         500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ dapper/main amd64 Packages >```
> ````

you need to install `libqt3-mt` package into the schroot and then proceed.

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert. I think I'm facing dependency issues. It seems like its trying to remove the libqt3-mt, and install bunch of others. I came thus far -appended to question.

Comment: It seems that you use wrong method of package installation. You just need simple `apt-get` inside schroot - `schroot -c precise -u root apt-get install libqt3-mt`. Your method added the problems...

Comment: thanks. Tried this as soon as I can; got the appended response. Still giving dependency error. Should I start from scratch, what do you think?

Comment: I think you should start from scratch. I have tested [my instruction](https://askubuntu.com/a/1002350/66509) before publishing it, so please follow it precisely. Last time I have checked it in 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, you are a gentlemen. I got the qtstalker launch, but it crashed with Child terminated by signal ‘Segmentation fault’ message...During the reinstallation, I got error at the final dpkg. Appended the screen message with errors. Thanks again, hopefully this software pays dividend for all your efforts :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't reproduce the problem.